# what getShippingDescription() provide in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I am trying to get `Shipping Method` , so I am using

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface')->get($orderid);

$order->getShippingDescription()
```

It gives me something like `Free Ground Shipping`, `Shipping Table Rates - 2-day`

Should just be `2 -day` or `Ground Shipping`.
I don't know how `getShippingDescription()` gives me extra details and what is this `Shipping Table Rates`?

I tried this method also `$order->getShippingMethod();` gives me `freeshipping_freeshipping, freeshipping two times`

I checked `sales_order` table also, so getShippingDescription() content is coming from that column(shipping description).

I tried this also
`$orderInfo->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod()` gives me null

Answer (score 1):

First, check the `sales_order` database table, you will find a column name `shipping_description` and `getShippingDescription` function return result like `Free Ground Shipping`, `Shipping Table Rates - 2-day`.

At `freeshipping_freeshipping` ,the first  `freeshipping` Carrier code and second `freeshipping` is means  Shipping method code.

```
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $method->setPrice('0.00');
    $method->setCost('0.00');
```

At Magento,`ShippingMethod`  =  `carrierCode_ShippingMethodCode`,

So, what why you getting `freeshipping_freeshipping`.

At Magento every shipping Carrie has single Carrier code but can have multiple Method code. An example is the Matrix Shipping Rate.

getShippingDescription() of Sales order object give the combination of

```
CarrierTitle_MethodTitle.
```

Most of the cases, Carrier title basically from `System Configuration field` **`title`**  of that Shipping Carrier.

If you want to just `2 -day` or `Ground Shipping`  then you have to Call System configuration value of Shipping carrier title field.

```
 protected $scopeConfig;

   const XML_PATH_TITLE_FIELD = 'carriers/flatrate/title';

   public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
   {
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
   }

   /**
   * Sample function returning config value
   **/

  public function getShippingtitle() {
     $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

     return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_TITLE_FIELD, $storeScope);


     }
```

then `str_replace($order->getShippingDescription())`

`str_replace($this->getShippingtitle(),"",$order->getShippingDescription());`

Comment: Hi @Amit Bera can you help me with this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262749/customize-account-setting-form-in-magento-2