# Customize Account setting form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, forms, change-password

In Magento 2, the previous `Account Setting` edit form has a different layout, like for changing `password` user has to select the checkbox and then text boxes for password updates pop up,

I am changing that layout

So I removed all the checkboxes, and put change password in the different form.
and also I included `first name`, `last name`, `email address`, `gender`, `dob` in password form and display it to none.

The issue is, password update doesn't work, On digging up I found the `script` code in `edit form` phtml

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=change-email], [data-role=change-password]": {
        "changeEmailPassword": {
            "titleChangeEmail": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email'))) ?>",
            "titleChangePassword": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password'))) ?>",
            "titleChangeEmailAndPassword": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email and Password'))) ?>"
        }
    },
    "[data-container=new-password]": {
        "passwordStrengthIndicator": {
            "formSelector": "form.form-edit-account"
        }
    }
}
```

Code for checkboxes which I removed

```
 <div class="field choice">
        <input type="checkbox" name="change_email" id="change-email" data-role="change-email" value="1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Change Email')) ?>" class="checkbox" />
        <label class="label" for="change-email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="field choice">
        <input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change-password" data-role="change-password" value="1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Change Password')) ?>"<?php if ($block->getChangePassword()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
        <label class="label" for="change-password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
```

So that's clear script is linked to those checkboxes, as it assigns some kind of listener to `[data-role=change-email]` and `[data-role=change-password]`, 
How can I change it to so that my `Update Password` will work?

I even tried adding those checkboxes and displayed it none still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this quick-fix type solution as provided below.

1) Instead removeing I made the two containers div hidden for Email and Password change check box.

```
<div class="field choice" style="display:none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="change_email" id="change-email" data-role="change-email" value="1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Change Email')) ?>" class="checkbox" />
        <label class="label" for="change-email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Email')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="field choice" style="display:none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change-password" data-role="change-password" value="1" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Change Password')) ?>"<?php if ($block->getChangePassword()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
        <label class="label" for="change-password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
```

2) use a window load event to trigger click event for Email and Password change checkbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        requirejs(['jquery'],function(jQuery){
            (function($) {
                $(window).load(function () {
                    $("#change-password").trigger('click');
                    $("#change-email").trigger('click');


                });                 

            })(jQuery);
        });
</script>
```

3) Do not put change password in the different form.

[image]

Comment: this has a flaw, whenever you want to update name only then you have to update the password also, as its a required field